Map doesn't load after fetching current location. How can I fix?
I am building a dashboard for a potential package tracking application. I am using Leaflet and OpenStreetMap for now.
I am trying to fetch the user's current location and show it on the map. Unfortunately, when I fetch the location, the map goes blank. See the attached images. When the location is fetched, you'll see a blue dot. I don't understand what am I doing wrong. I have attached the relevant code here:
HTML:
I have included this in head: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
Then closed the body and other tags.
CSS:
/* Map Container */
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  float: right;
}

.leaflet-popup-tip-container {
  display: none; /* Hide the default popup tip */
}

.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
  border-radius: 10px; /* Optional: Rounded corners for the popup */
}

JavaScript:
// Initialize and add the map
function initMap() {
  const map = L.map("map").setView([12.9716, 77.5946], 10); // Bengaluru

  const tileLayer = L.tileLayer(
    "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    {
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    }
  ).addTo(map); // Immediately add the tile layer

  let userMarker = null; // Initialize userMarker as null

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        const lat = position.coords.latitude;
        const lng = position.coords.longitude;

        // Update the map view
        map.setView([lat, lng], 10);

        if (!userMarker) {
          // Create marker on initial location fetch
          userMarker = L.circleMarker([lat, lng], {
            color: "blue",
            radius: 10,
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
          }).addTo(map);

          // Create and bind the popup (only once)
          userMarker
            .bindPopup("Your current location.", {
              autoClose: true, // Keep popup open on click
              closeOnClick: true, // Prevent popup from closing on map click
            })
            .openPopup();
        } else {
          // Update existing marker position
          userMarker.setLatLng([lat, lng]).openPopup(); // Re-open the popup
        }
      },
      () => {
        alert("Unable to retrieve your location.");
      }
    );
  } else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by your browser.");
  }
}

window. Onload = initMap();


Media Assets:



I tried your code and it works as expected. Have you tried to log the coordinates to the console?

@Thomas yes, I have. Doesn't load for me unfortunately. Tried MS Edge, Chrome, Brave and Firefox, same issues.

Have you tested it on a different device as well? Could it be that your GPS is returning invalid coordinates: lat < -90 || lat > 90 and long < -180 || long >  180? I tried your code here and it works for me.
